# How to make event.respond but just first sender will be responded? with Telethon

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot, telethon

I have a question regarding the event on the telethon.

So, I want to make something like event.respond(). But only the first sender will be responded by the bot. If there is a second sender - and the rest are not responded to by bots.

How to make such a method? Thanks a lot for your answer. I use Telethon.

I've tried using the exit program method, it's not very effective. I have to restart the program to start it again. I want a method other than this, without having to restart the program.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the first sender somewhere and check it in subsequent events. One way to do it us using a global:

```py
allowed_id = None

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def handler(event):
    global allowed_id
    if allowed_id is None:
        allowed_id = event.sender_id

    if event.sender_id == allowed_id:
        await event.respond('allowed')

...
```

However, I would recommend to learn some more Python first.